# Imprimir en una misma posicion de pantalla en C

Tags: c, imprimir, printf

/*Buenas, me pidieron que simule un reloj digital en un minuto imprimiendo cada incremento de segundo, pero debo hacerlo en una misma posicion de pantalla. Tal como lo tengo armado, el código me imprime bien los valores pero visualmente en forma de lista (que no es lo que me piden). Si alguien sabe alguna manera de lograr esto seria de gran ayuda. A continuacion dejo el fragmento de codigo. Muchas gracias. Probé usar fflush(stdout) pero tampoco funciona*/

```
for(i=0; i<60; i++){
    seg = i;
    min = 25;
    hora = 14;
    printf ("Hora: %d:%d:%d\n", hora, min, seg);
    usleep(1000000); // Espero un segundo para volver a ejecutar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Investiga sobre **`system("CLS")`** para windows o **`system("clear")`** para sistema linux, OJO en ocasiones puede llegar a no funcionar y agrega la libreria **`#include<stdlib.h>`**

Ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int i,seg,min,hora;
    for(i=0; i<60; i++){
    seg = i;
    min = 25;
    hora = 14;
    system("clear");
    printf ("Hora: %d:%d:%d\n", hora, min, seg);
    usleep(1000000); // Espero un segundo para volver a ejecutar
}

    return 0;
}
```

También te falta programar para que los minutos y las horas aumenten o disminuyan.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda. Ahí me funcionó perfectamente. No programé el aumento de los minutos y horas porque solo debo simularlo por un minuto. Muchas gracias. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Espero que te ayude, así como pones la opción de `\n` para un salto de linea, `\r` sirve para sobre escribir dentro de la misma linea. Solo cambia eso y veras como se sobre escribe cada vez que pasa el tiempo, espero te sirva